# Spell Check in VIM Latex Suite not working after a particular word

Tags: vim, vim-latex

In latex I need to type the sequence`$G^{\{ x \}}$` to get the desired equation. The equation works fine, but after this spell check does not work for the remaining text. Spell check works fine before the occurrence of this word and works find if I delete such occurrence. If the same sequence occurs outside maths mode i.e not inside `$ $`, then there is no problem.

I get issues with syntax highlighting also after the occurrence of that sequence.
What is the issue here.

Comment: I do not seem to be able to recreate your problem. I don't think it is particularly related with that exact sequence. Sometimes it happens in long files, that the syntax highlighting is messed up. Try executing `:set ft=tex`.

Comment: That did not help. if i change the sequence to `$G^{(x )}$ it works, so the problem is very particular about this sequence particularly `\}` and `\{`.

Comment: Try adding `%stopzone` after that sequence.

Comment: @DurgaDatta Does this problem still exist? Has there been an update that solved the problem? Does using `\(` and `\)` instead of `$` help (see [vonbrand’s answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85569/16595))?

Comment: I think we need version numbers and more detail (exactly what needs to be done to get the issue) to help, and even then it's possibly more of a bug report than anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try `\(G^{\{x\}}\)`. This style (`\(...\)` instead of `$...$`, `\[...\]` instead of `$$...$$`) is more robust (a forgotten end won't mess up reams of text, it is visually clearer where it starts/ends), and is less likely to mess up the editor's parsing.